# Git post-receive hook with two servers

Tags: git, deployment, server, githooks, git-bare

We have two servers - ServerA (bare repo) and ServerB (hosted project folder). Every time a developer pushes local changes to ServerA they should be automatically pushed to ServerB.

What I have tried so far:
I created a post-receive script in bare_repo/hooks/.
The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production..."
        git --work-tree=remoteaddress --git-dir=/volume1/_Repos/test.git checkout -f
    else
        echo "Ref $ref successfully received.  Doing nothing: only the master branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

Where remoteaddress is something like *IPServerB:/path/to/hosted_project_folder*.

My entire approach:

*hosted_project_folder* already existed.
Then on ServerA:

```
git clone --mirror IPServerB:/path/to/hosted_project_folder
git fetch --all
```

Add post-receive script in hooks.

On Client:

```
git clone IPServerA:/path/to/bare_repo
```

Add changes at Client and push it to ServerA:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "add something"
git push origin master
```

Where origin is *IPServerA:path/to/bare_repo*

At this point I get an error:

```
remote: fatal: Invalid path '/volume1/_Repos/test.git/IPServerB:C:': No such file or directory
```

However, if we use one server for bare repo and hosted project folder then it works.

Comment: For working tree files, Git uses the system-provided operations (`mkdir`, `rmdir`, `open`, `symlink`, etc., calls from C code). Whatever they allow, Git allows; whatever they don't, Git doesn't. Windows does allow mounting remote file systems, but with various restrictions that may be problematic (or may not—I'm no Windows expert). It's generally not wise to *use* such extensions because they tend not to provide the POSIX file semantics that Git requires.

Comment: In short, "don't do that": do deployment with something that actually does deployment, rather than trying to whack Git into acting as a deployment system.

Comment: @edu : I'm a bit lost between your IPs. Which one is the server with the bare repo ? `serverA` ?

Comment: @LeGEC yes, serverA is the server with bare repos

Comment: @torek so is it not a good practice, to synchronize the bare repo with our deployment repo? Should we do it manually?

Comment: What I'm saying is that Git itself makes a lousy deployment system. It's an OK version control system, but it was never intended to be a deployment system, and when pressed into service to *act* as one, it performs badly. Use Git as a VCS, not as a deployment mechanism. Use some other software to deploy the commit stored in Git.

Answer (score 0):

A few points to fix :

a. appart from `git push` and `git fetch`, git works 100% locally.

`git --work-tree=someip:somewhere` doesn't work -- `git` expects its worktree to be something that is mounted on the local filesystem -- you should have `ServerA` push to `ServerB`, or `ServerB` fetch from `ServerA`.

Then you take extra actions to actually deploy on `ServerB`.

b. the `post-receive` script will be run synchronously : `git push` from your client will trigger a call to `post-receive`, and wait for the script to complete.

So you probably want to just trigger a deployment, but not wait for it to complete. e.g :

- trigger a deployment through http : `curl https://serverB/myproject/trigger _deployement`
- or some job (a cron job ? a daemon which watches the modifications in a directory ?) that expects a change in a file : `ssh serverB touch trigger_dir/trigger_file`
- or start a script asynchronously on `ServerA` : `nohup deploy.sh "$hash" >> /tmp/deploy.log 2>&1`
- or ...